# ES6 default parameter not defined in arguments

Tags: ecmascript-6

Default parameters aren't assigned to the arguments Array like Object :

```
function fn(test = "test") { 
 console.log(arguments); //[]
}
```

This might be usefull to know only what the user passes to the function, but it seems tricky too.
Will this change?

Comment: You're asking for opinions about what will happen to the standards in the future. (Would you expect them to introduce a non-backwards-compatible change to the spec though?)

Comment: A quick search through the spec didn't turn up anything related to this, but my **guess** is that arguments cannot be deprecated but that it will not be supported by any new features. For example, the spec explicitly states that rest params are not added to the arguments object. If you call your function `fn(1,2,3)` then arguments will be `{"0": 1, "1": 2...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this will not change.

In fact it already *did* change - previously every index on the `arguments` object was mapped to the respective parameter variable for reading and writing (a horror to reason about!). This proved to have devastating performance implications as it prevented a lot of engine optimisations, and was deprecated in ES5 (however, for compatibility reasons, only in the new strict mode). In ES6, the behavior is also deprecated in sloppy mode functions if they use new ES6 features in their parameter list (like destructuring, default initialisers or rest syntax).

The `arguments` object is [just a simple object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createunmappedargumentsobject)  with the argument values that were passed to the function. Notice that defaults are not passed, it's just syntactic sugar for initialising variables in the begin of the function body.
If mapped to scope variables, it's [much more complicated](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createmappedargumentsobject).